# How can I undefine a function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Often I need to undefine a function in clojure. If I define something with defn how can I undefine it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have:

```
(def x 42)
```

It might be useful to unbind the var:

```
(.unbindRoot #'x)
```

Now, if you try this

```
x
```

You get:

```
#<Unbound Unbound: #'user/x>
```

Answer (score 40):

There is no one-argument version, because the same Var can be mapped in more than one namespace. If you are working from the REPL, you often want to unbind from the user namespace, e.g.

```
(ns-unmap 'user 'symbol-to-unbind)
```

The first argument to ns-unmap can be a symbol or a namespace, and the second argument should be a symbol.

Comment: Any reason why ns-unmap can't just take a single qualified symbol, e.g. `'user/symbol-to-unbind`?

Answer (score 21):

I think, that you can use **ns-unmap** to do this.

P.S. Couldn't add this code into comment, so i put it here. To unmap function in current namespace, you need to use following code:

```
(ns-unmap *ns* 'method)
```

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when I use (ns-unmap ::some-method). Is there a one argument version?