# Destroy variable in clojure

Tags: clojure

When using the repl, sometimes you want to destroy a variable because it somehow get in the way of your programming (most usually namespace collisions).

Is there a way to destroy a variable in clojure?

```
user>(def x 1)
#'user/x
user>(aggressive-destroy! x)
nil
user>x
Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570826/how-can-i-undefine-a-function-in-clojure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**[ns-unmap](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-unmap)**

```
user=> (def my-var "this is my-var!")
#'user/my-var
user=> (println my-var)
this is my-var!
nil
user=> (ns-unmap 'user 'my-var)
nil
user=> (println my-var)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: my-var in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:13) 
user=>
```

Comment: Usually easier to use `*ns*` than `'user` here, especially if you're in a namespace with a long name.

Comment: saved me from tedious restart of swank! Awesome!